# applying data-bind dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I edited HTML element in javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('newc')[0].innerHTML=document.getElementsByClassName('newc')[0].innerHTML+string;
```

now `newc` class had a component `binded` with it in html document. But after inserting the extra html part i thought that new html part would bind the property itself, but it didn't. So i want to know how to implement `data-bind=""` dynamically through JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

JQuery:

```
$('.newc').data('bind', 'value_for_bind');
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('newc')[0].setAttribute("data-bind", "value_for_bind");
```

Hope this helps.

Regards